# Ideas of what to code using C, XML or JavaScript and Win 32 API

Tags: javascript, c++, c, xml

Maybe an unusual question. I am starting work at a new company (my first job) and wanted to create some dummy program to make sure I'm familiar with their set up when I start. I've been told that I'll be coding in C/C++ and should be familiar with XML, JavaScript and Win 32 API.

Can anyone think of a program I could create in C that could incorporate XML or JavaScript?

Thanks

Comment: Try a web browser (j.k. don't actually do that)

Comment: If you just got hired, then the best thing to do is run their code and learn as much as you can about it. Pretty straight forward.

Comment: @Lirik I'm not working there yet, wanted to get a headstart so I don't have access to their code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for XML you could write an XML parser (not especially full featured).
As for javascript, I would tell you to write a javascript interpreter, but no, don't do that :D

You could try out QML and have fun mixing JavaScript (for the GUI) and C++ for the business logic.

EDIT: I don't know about the Win32 API.